# How to prevent from Nunit closing browser after each test using Selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit

When I'm using Nunit for testing Selenium WebDriver in visual studio, after each method annotated with [Test] the browser closes.

I there a way to prevent it? 
Meaning having a few tests that will run on the same browser instance?

Here is what i'm doing:

```
class Controllers
{
    private static IWebDriver driver;


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\chromedriver_win32");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://github.com");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Alert()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyAlert")).Click();
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        Debug.WriteLine(alert.Text);
        alert.Accept();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Alert2()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("search_query")).SendKeys("The lion king");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("search-icon-legacy")).Submit();

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

**I basically want to go from Github to Youtube without the browser closing in between the tests.**

Comment: Stop TearingDown the test and instead Quit when needed?

Comment: @thelastchief Agreed. Best to change it to a `[OneTimeTearDown]` instead

Comment: thelastchief , that exactly what I needed!!

Comment: @Dgot Fantastic! Upvote my comment if it works!

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was using [TearDown] instead of using [OneTimeTearDown] which caused the browser to close after each test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.get()` in java or `driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";` in C# to navigate to a new url within the same instance.

Comment: There is no get in selenium webdriver c# binding

Comment: Sorry I added the C# way, I entered Java initially